# Noise spectrum of the thermal noise?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If we have a thermal noise generated by Brownian stochastic force $\xi (t)$, it has zero mean value. And its correlation function at temperature T is :
\begin{equation}
\langle\xi(t) \xi(t^{\prime})\rangle=\frac{\gamma_m}{\omega_m}\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi}e^{-i\omega(t-t^{\prime})}\omega\left[\coth\left(\frac{\hbar \omega}{2K_BT}\right )+1\right]
\end{equation}
And it said that the thermal noise spectrum is:
\begin{equation}
S_T(\omega)=(\gamma_m/\omega_m)\omega \coth(\hbar \omega/ 2k_BT)
\end{equation}

So how we derive the noise spectrum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The noise spectrum is the Fourier transform of the correlation function, as long as the correlation function is invariant under global time translation.
This is nice, because the Fourier transform of the correlation function you have there produces a delta function in frequency, which then makes the frequency integral totally trivial.

\begin{align}
S_T(\Omega) &\equiv
\int \langle \xi(0)\xi(t) \rangle e^{i \Omega t} dt\\
&= \frac{\gamma_m}{\omega_m} \int \int \frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \, dt \, e^{- i \omega t} e^{i \Omega t} \omega \left[ \coth\left(\frac{\hbar \omega}{2 k_b T} \right) + 1 \right] \\
&= \frac{\gamma_m}{\omega_m} \int \frac{d \omega}{2\pi} (2\pi) \delta(\Omega - \omega) \, \omega  \left[  \coth \left( \frac{\hbar \omega}{2 k_b T} \right) + 1 \right] \\
&= \frac{\gamma_m}{\omega_m} \Omega \left[  \coth \left( \frac{\hbar \Omega}{2 k_b T} \right) + 1 \right]
\end{align}

Comment: I seem to have an extra term in the square brackets which OP does not have in their formula. I'll have to go look at my notes to see whether OP's or my formula has an error. In any case, this is the general idea.

Comment: It's also possible that I goofed a minus sign in the exponential, but again that doesn't change the basic form of the equation.

Comment: @Mr.an 1) Did you figure out where either of us missed the +1 term? 2) Double check the signs in my equation. I don't remember which sign convention is used in the Fourier transform between the correlation function and the noise spectral density. 3) Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted once there is one which does in fact answer your question.

Comment: Hi,  1.   About the +1 term, at the moment I am not sure.  Maybe there is some kind of assumption, the process is Markovian or something like that.  2. The choice of sign for the Fourier transform is correct.

Comment: @Mr.an I have a strange feeling that I've encountered this mysterious +1 before. I think we just missed something simple. I need to check my notes though.

Comment: hi, about the +1 term you are wright. Since I am dealing with some physics problem, there is some assumption. In that case the argument of the $coth$ becomes very small. That means $coth$ is very large. Then we can neglect the $+1$ term.   :)